# AWS SDK authorization in ECS id failing, but not local

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk

I have a dockerized spring boot app running on AWS Fargate in a private subnet on ECS, sitting behind a load balancer. I created vpc PrivateLink Endpoints to AWS services such that the task has access to ECR, ECS, S3, etc for the purposes of building and saving the image. I also exposed an SNS endpoint so that the service can access SNS. I can see in the logs, traffic is reaching the spring boot app.

I created a user called “myapp-sns-access”, authorized it to publish to topics and generated programmatic credentials, stored them in AWS secrets manager, and have them passed in as environment variables inside the container definition, found under the task definition ("value-from" and secret arn).

The spring boot service has an endpoint that calls AWS SNS. I cannot figure out why I keep getting this error:

> com.amazonaws.services.sns.model.AmazonSNSException: '"SNS_SECRET_KEY":"XXXXX"}/20220811/us-east-1/sns/aws4_request' not a valid key=value pair (missing equal-sign) in Authorization header: 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential={"SNS_ACCESS_KEY_ID":"CORRECT_ACCESS_ID","SNS_SECRET_KEY":"CORRECT_SECRET_KEY"}/20220811/us-east-1/sns/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=amz-sdk-invocation-id;amz-sdk-request;amz-sdk-retry;host;user-agent;x-amz-date, Signature=XXXXREDACTEDXXXX'. (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: IncompleteSignature; Proxy: null)

I can see that the service is receiving the credentials from the AWS Secrets Manager (notice above), but I guess the AWS SDK is failing to handle the auth portion of the sns call for some reason that I cannot figure out.

Heres the gradle import:

> // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.amazonaws/aws-java-sdk
> implementation group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk', version: '1.12.253'

This all works locally, so I wonder if theres some weird auth flow / access to some auth server that I need to create an endpoint for in order for the service to create the auth headers correctly. I triple checked for typos with the secrets and refreshed them. I also opened up my security groups and allowed all traffic on all ports (for testing purposes).

Appreciate your time.

Update: I swapped out the PrivateLink endpoints for a Nat gateway, and I tried role based authorization and its still not working.

Comment: use instance role, never create credentials and put it in instances. (Use task role if you use ECS tasks)

Comment: How would I test this locally?

Comment: @HùngNguyễn Can you share a reference why this is a bad practice?

Comment: You can search google for that. Create instant role with enough SNS permission and try.  Feel free to use your key on local.